# How to understand if a folder is in the right partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, ubuntu-11.10

I've just installed an ubuntu server (11.10) with two partitions, one is a ssd hard drive and the second one is a raid 1 drive. During installation process I chose to put the home directory inside the raid partition. Well everything should be ok, but I'm quite new in linux so I would like to know if there is a command that shows me if the home folder is in the right partition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type 'df /home' in a terminal window and that will tell you how your home partition is mounted.